# Molly and a pseudocode

Tags: riddle, computer-puzzle

Molly was given a pseudocode by her teacher and told her you need to understand the pseudocode to answer the riddle.

Riddle:

> I am _________ like universe and stars 
>   You will find me in computer _________ 
>   I start over and over until you are _________ 
>   Who am I? I am _________

I will add more phrases as hints if nobody is able to find the answer...

Here is the pseudocode it is a hint:

```
var a = "2#12jJIUP^()";
if(!a){
return "123456";
}else{
key(a);
}

key(z){
 lock(z); 
}

lock(z){
key(z);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> If we follow the pseudocode it gives us an infinite loop...

So the riddle must be

> I am **endless (infinite)** like universe and stars
>  You will find me in computer **program (infinite loop)**
>  I start over and over until you are **stuck (freezed)**
>  Who I am I am **infinite**?